# Python local variable change

Tags: python, scope

What I essentially want is a helper function (either inside our outside the class, whatever will work), in order to change the value of a local variable declared within the function.

```
class MainClass:
    def importantFunction():
        truthValue1 = False
        truthValue2 = False
        change(truthValue1,truthValue2)
        return truthValue1 && truthValue2

def changeBoolValue(val1,val2):
val1 = not val1
val2 = not val2
```

I want to change the value of truthValue1 and truthValue2 with the help of an outside function somehow. I've tried moving it inside the class and using self which didn't work, and I really would prefer to not make truthValue1,2 global to the class. How can I manage this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change values you need to pass them in list for example:

```
class MainClass:
    def importantFunction(self):  # don't forget self
        truthValues = [False, False]
        changeBoolValue(truthValues)
        return truthValues[0] and truthValues[1]   # using `and`, not `&&`

def changeBoolValue(val):
    val[0] = not val[0]
    val[1] = not val[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this due to the way that Python handles memory of list objects vs reassignments to primitive types?

Comment: In Python, as @Tomforge said, boolean is immutable type, you pass it to functions only by value. Only thing is put it in some sort of container, like `list` in this example, which is mutable and passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean is an immutable type in Python, so you can't pass it by reference. Consider wrapping it in a list(a mutable type) like @Andrej Kesely's answer, or use returns.

```
class MainClass:
    def importantFunction():
        truthValue1 = False
        truthValue2 = False
        truthValue1, truthValue2 = changeBoolValue(truthValue1, truthValue2)
        return truthValue1 && truthValue2

def changeBoolValue(val1, val2):
    return not val1, not val2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reassign the names:

```
truthValue1, truthValue2 = change(truthValue1, truthValue2)

def change(val1, val2):
    val1 = not val1
    val2 = not val2
    return val1, val2
```

It might be better to encapsulate in some way:

```
class Truth:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val1 = False
        self.val2 = False

    def change(self):
        self.val1 = not self.val1
        self.val2 = not self.val2
```

Then:

```
truth = Truth()
truth.change()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from the `change` function and then reassign the variables in order to change their values

```
class MainClass:
    def importantFunction():
        truthValue1 = False
        truthValue2 = False
        thruthValue1, truthValue2 = change(truthValue1,truthValue2)
        return truthValue1 && truthValue2

def changeBoolValue(val1,val2):
    val1 = not val1
    val2 = not val2
    return val1, val2
```